# Parent hair to body without deforming

Tags: hair, rigify

I’m using blender’s hair curve feature and I want to parent it to a body that is using a rigify armature, but when I parent it and move the head it deforms the guide mesh so it seems to re-calculate the hair. This means the hair shape changes with every head motion. How can I parent it to the body without the shape changing like this? Thanks!